# Systemd + Python Script that runs VLC doesn't allow dbus control access to VLC

Tags: systemd, python, vlc, cvlc

OK, this is weird. I have been battling this all day & have been unsuccessful as of yet. I am working on a project that is Python based. The project is started via systemd scripts. Weird thing is vlc/cvlc works to an extent, but there is no dbus control. If I run the python app from the command line, everything works perfectly. Running the app from systemd is the wonkiness.

For instance, when it is run with the following code & service script, I can't control vlc with dbus. If I run the python outside of systemd script, I can access the dbus. There is another weird issue that is a side effect of whatever is causing this problem. It will run 1080 vid just fine but not 4k. Try it out with the following & let me know if you can figure it out. I greatly appreciate any & all help. Thanks!

PYTHON CODE (testvlc):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

vid = 'somevideo.mp4'
cmd = 'DISPLAY=:0 cvlc -f --no-osd %s -L' % vid
Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
    print("Hello!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

SYSTEMD SCRIPT (testvlc.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Test VLC From Python Script

[Service]
User=user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -D -S testvlc -m /home/user/testvlc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should write it up as an answer, not modify the question. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, I have "undeleted" my previous answer, wasn't sure exactly how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Unit]
Description=Test VLC From Python Script

[Service]
User=user
Environment="DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -D -S testvlc -m /home/user/testvlc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also, if you run this from `~/.config/systemd/user` it will run everything just fine including 4K. Changed the wantedby to `default.target` & add a `After=graphical-session.target`, remover the `User=` & the `Environment=`, & use `systemctl --user`

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing something similar, in the sense that I want to control VLC from python via DBus.

What I did was to setup VLC as a DBus activatable service. To do that I needed to do two things:

1. Define the DBus service
2. Define the systemd unit file for VLC, which will be activated when dbus detects activity in #1.

For the DBus service, I needed to create a file in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services`. I called it `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.service`. I couldn't find the way to set it up in a user directory, unfortunately.

```
# /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.service
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
Exec=/bin/false
SystemdService=vlc.service
```

With this information, we tell DBus that any activity regarding the bus defined by `Name` (`org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc`) will need to activate the service `vlc.service`. Therefore, we need to define such service via a systemd unit file. You can place this file in either `~/.config/sytemd/user/` (for a user service) or in `/usr/lib/systemd/user/` (for a system service).

```
# vlc.service
[Unit]
Description=VLC media player DBus activated service

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
Environment=""
ExecStart=/home/jbellon/test/ytube-dl/vlc/install/usr/bin/vlc -I "dummy"
```

Note that the service type here is DBus. You can check out the properties of DBus services in the Systemd unit file documentation.

It has been a while since I got it right (and I didn't dare to change it since), but I think I had problems using `cvlc`, so I went straight with the main program using the dummy interface (`-I "dummy"`), which is basically the same thing.

Once I got this sorted out, you just need to make sure Systemd knows about the VLC service (`systemctl daemon-reload`) and so does DBus (you need to restart DBus for this).

To test it out, you could try to query anything to the DBus service, such as introspecting the interface:

```
$ systemctl --user status vlc --lines 0
● vlc.service - VLC media player DBus activated service
   Loaded: loaded (vlc.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$ gdbus introspect --session --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc -o /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2 &> /dev/null
$ systemctl --user status vlc --lines 0
● vlc.service - VLC media player DBus activated service
   Loaded: loaded (vlc.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-17 22:43:53 BST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 56522 (vlc)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 38349)
   Memory: 2.0M
      CPU: 13ms
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/vlc.service
           └─56522 /usr/bin/vlc -I dummy
```